# Using hashed password for imap_open PHP function

Tags: php, security, email, imap

Is there a way to use a hashed password with imap_open() function? I have to hide somehow that password even from myself. But cannot find a way to do that. The actual PHP script works on the Linux server. A few people have sudo rights there. So, they may see that password anyway.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Such a feature would defeat the very purpose of password hashing:

The standard password scheme is for the resource that requires authentication to store a hash of your password, and that you submit to it your plain password. If the hash of your password matches the stored hash, the authentication succeeds. The purpose of this is that the resource never needs to know your password, nor can anyone who breaks in discover which password you used.

Now you're asking that the user be allowed to hash her own password and submit the hash, and that the resource then just compare the submitted hash with the stored hash. But this would effectively turn the hash itself into a plain password which is stored verbatim! Anyone who gets access to the stored hashes would now have immediate access to the resource, thus utterly derailing the very purpose of only storing a hash of the password!

Comment: I got your point of view. But if somebody knows the plain text password for IMAP then he can easily use it to access to the mail box. So, how to avoid such situation?

Comment: How to prevent someone who knows the password from accessing the resource? Phew, I don't know. If the policy is that the password grants access, then you really can't without defeating the purpose of the password, non?